# Android 11 not fetching path for file

Tags: android, android-studio, permissions, storage, android-11

I have been working to fetch file path from storage till now,
For example file path is /storage/emulated/0/Download/NTL_ANDRODI_DOGMA_SYSTEMS_SRL_A_SOCIO_UNICO_TEST NEW.afgclic

After android 11 it's unable to fetch FilePath. After giving permission

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

It's allowing for Android 11 also, but app is getting rejected by Play store. Since the permission cannot be used without a specific reason and its allowed only for filemanager or antivirus app. Now the point is how other app manages to work on Android 11 for fetching files.

I have been using READ and WRITE storage permission to access file from external storage. Files are required to verify license from other library information.

Comment: How did your app determine that path? How did the file land on the device? If your app ddn't create the file it has no access. It is unclear what you mean with fetch filePath. Further you did not tell what goes wrong.

Comment: Till now the path was determined by 
*RealPathUtil.getRealPath(getApplicationContext(), data.getData())*

Comment: You should not have done that. And you did not answer my questions. And further you did not tell where you got `data` from.

Comment: @PriyankaSinghal `File createFile = new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(null)+File.separator+"My App");` Is app specific Storage (Private storage) required `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` Permission?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed it by fetching path from Google drive

```
private static String getDriveFilePath(Uri uri, Context context) {
Uri returnUri = uri;
Cursor returnCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(returnUri, null, null, null, null);
/*
 * Get the column indexes of the data in the Cursor,
 *     * move to the first row in the Cursor, get the data,
 *     * and display it.
 * */
int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
returnCursor.moveToFirst();

String name = (returnCursor.getString(nameIndex));
String size = (Long.toString(returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex)));
File file = new File(context.getCacheDir(), name);
try {
    InputStream inputStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    int read = 0;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    int bytesAvailable = inputStream.available();

    //int bufferSize = 1024;
    int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);

    final byte[] buffers = new byte[bufferSize];
    while ((read = inputStream.read(buffers)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(buffers, 0, read);
    }
    Log.e("File Size", "Size " + file.length());
    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();
    Log.e("File Path", "Path " + file.getPath());
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
}
    return file.getPath();
}     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `Android 11` you have to use `Scoped Storage` if you want full access of storage.

If you want to access public directories like Documents, Download etc.You can use `legacyStorage`.

---

In Your `Manifest`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
      android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" 

/>
```

If you want to access full storage you can use `Scoped Storage`

Add Permissions In Your `Manifest`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

Now just ask for Permission in your code

```
    if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);

        if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {

        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
            intent.setData(uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        return true;

    } else {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.v("Permission", "Storage Permission is granted");
                return true;
            } else {
                Log.v("Permission", "Storage Permission is revoked");
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        } else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            Log.v("Permission", "Storage Permission is granted");
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The android 11 introduced scoped storage to handle storage. Refer to https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage for reference.

Comment: Can you please share a working sample code for easy implementation

Answer (score 0):

Its very difficult to answer your question.We need some information like what you do with files in your app.What is the usecase of filepath in your application.

- If you really need file to be accessed via file path then you can copy the file to your apps private directory(not reasonable for working with large video or other files).
- You can use contentResolver to open fileDescriptor to access the file.
- You can open e folderSelector intent to let user select a folder where you can get full access to this folder using DocumentFile class.

Best way would be to replace your filepath dependency with uri(if possible).

learn more about scoped storage at  [Here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage)

Comment: Updated question for better understanding.

How to do it? *Best way would be to replace your filepath dependency with uri(if possible).*

Comment: Very strange reaction @Priyanka Singhal as you have already a nice uri. Your trouble started where you tried to replace your uri for a file path.

Answer (score 0):

In android 11, there comes scoped storage feature to handle external storage.
for better residue file mgmnt and access mgmnt.
Here's Philip Lackner's playlist that I followed:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TkOzcyzH1hU&list=PLQkwcJG4YTCR9jZq8O19nUL2hLqmLYX4M